# How to read a UNC path in ERLANG / ELIXIR

Tags: erlang, elixir, unc

Please how may we read a **UNC** path in Elixir or Erlang?

I have tried the File module in Elixir , but it does not work.

```
Erlang/OTP 21 [erts-10.1] [64-bit] [smp:6:6] [ds:6:6:10] [async-threads:1]

Interactive Elixir (1.7.4) - press Ctrl+C to exit (type h() ENTER for help)
iex(1)> s =  ~S"\\flsv\Finance_Dept\FUND ACCOUNTING UNIT\\27112018"   
"\\\\flsv\\Finance_Dept\\FUND ACCOUNTING UNIT\\27112018"
iex(2)> s = "//flsv/Finance_Dept/FUND ACCOUNTING UNIT/27112018/"  
"//flsv/Finance_Dept/FUND ACCOUNTING UNIT/27112018/"
iex(3)> File.ls s
{:error, :enoent}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you on Windows? Then it might help to upgrade to erts-10.1.1

See http://erlang.org/pipermail/erlang-questions/2018-October/096495.html

> File access through UNC paths works again on Windows.
>                   This regression was introduced in OTP 21.